Attempting to perform a major upgrade with Installshield 2022 behaves as a downgrade
I am attempting to create an installer to upgrade my software to version 2.0.0.0 using InstallShield 2022.
I have changed the Product Version from 1.0.38 to 2.0.0.0, got a new GUID for the Product Code, ensured the Generate new Package Code field is set to "yes", created a major upgrade item set to "Products sharing my upgrade code" and "Any earlier version", as well as created a clone of my original release to test the major upgrade. When I build the clone and attempt to upgrade from an installed version of 1.0.38 to my test 2.0.0.0 version, I get an error message that says "A newer version is already installed..." and then it fails the upgrade. I can't understand why this happening.
I haven't actually changed/added/deleted any of the files that get installed, I just wanted to test that major upgrade would work in the future for my software. Could it be something with the default ISPreventdowngrade item?
The detect property for ISPreventDowngrade is ISFOUNDNEWERPRODUCTVERSION
And the detect property for my new major upgrade item called NewUpgradeEntry1 is ISACTIONPROP1.
These should be defaults and I did not do anything with them before I built the 2.0.0.0 installer

UPDATE: If I delete the ISPreventDowngrade default item from Media->Upgrades, then I can perform the major upgrade. the problem is that deleting this now allows downgrades to occur and if 2.0.0.0 is installed, then 1.038 can be successfully installed afterwards as well and you wind up with both installed at the same time. I want this prevented while maintaing the major upgade capability

what was the setting for ISPreventDowngrade ?

The settings for the ISPreventDowngrade item were "products sharing my Upgrade Code" and  "Any earlier version" on the common tab and on the advanced tab, Include minimum version: yes, Include maximum version: no, Exclude specified languages: no, Detect only: yes, Detect Property: ISFOUNDNEWERPRODUCTVERSION, Continue On Failure: no, Migrate Feature States: No

Settings for ISPreventDowngrade is not correct. Instead of "Any Earlier version" option, Select "Within a specific range of versions". Uncheck "Version Range Inclusive". In min version, specify the current Product version. e.g 2.0.0.0 and left max version empty. This should work.

While this does allow for a major upgrade to occur, in my testing, this does not prevent 1.x.x.x from being installed after a major upgrade from 1x.x.x to 2.0.0.0

Possibly, I need to look at the currently installed version, and then get it's Product Version and check against the product version being installed? Like if its higher than the Product Version trying to be installed, then prevent the downgrade? Is that even possible??

I guess you did ISPreventDowngrade changes in 2.0.0.0 only. Version 1.0 isn't aware of it. Also, please validate if product code are different and upgrade code are same for 2.0 and 1.0

Are you suggesting change the min version to 2.0.0.0 in ISPreventDowngrade in a 1.x installer build? I added that change for the first 2.x installer build and it did not work
